# How to add test-specific user properties to report with pytest-reportlog?

Tags: pytest

Say I have a test

```py
# contents of test_foo.py

import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("value,expected", [(2, 4), (4, 16)])
def test_square(value: int, expected: int):
    assert value**2 == expected
```

and I want to return a JSON report of the test with [`pytest-reportlog`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-reportlog). How can I add data to the report in each test? Specifically, I would like to add the value of `value` and `expected` to the report for each test.

I run the tests with

```
pytest --report-log report.json
```

and I have `pytest==6.2.1` and `pytest-reportlog==0.1.2` installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `record_property` fixture (see [examples](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#record-property-example)). This fixture allows you to use a callable with the signature `record_property(name: str, value: object) -> None`

```py
import typing as ty
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("value,expected", [(2, 4), (4, 16)])
def test_square(
    record_property: ty.Callable[[str, ty.Any], None], value: int, expected: int
):
    record_property("value", value)
    record_property("expected", expected)
    assert value**2 == expected
```

These values can be access in the `user_properties` key of the JSON objects for these tests.

For example:

```
"user_properties": [["value", 2], ["expected", 4]]
```